# \hbar is not coming properly in pdf output while using {mathptmx}

Tags: math-mode, pdftex

`\hbar` is printing perfectly in both PS and PDF formats while using standard fonts. However if I am using Times New Roman fonts, the PS file is showing a correct `\hbar` but the PDF file is not showing it properly. It is giving a bar over h (should be h cross).

Including these two packages (shown below) creates all the problems.

System information: TeXnicCenter, MiKTeX2.9, Windows 7

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

Example TeX file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{mathptmx}  

\begin{document}  
The Zeeman Hamiltonian can be written as  
\begin{eqnarray}   
\mathcal{H}_z &=& -{\mu . B}\\  
            &=& -\mu_z . B_z = -\hbar {I_z} \gamma B_0 = -\hbar \omega_0 {I_z},  
\end{eqnarray}  

\end{document}
```

Note: No error message is shown. The PS file is showing a perfect 'hbar' symbol, but not the PDF. I guess my PDF is not supporting the 'hbar' symbol

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. In my test the problem doesn't show, so this might depend on other settings you're doing.

Comment: MWE included, see the main post above.

Comment: Compiling the example with `pdflatex`, but also with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` gives the expected result.

Comment: Thanks. But the same example is not working for direct LaTeX => PDF . So I am first creating the PS output by LaTeX => PS and then converting PS into PDF.    However the same example is working for LaTeX=>PDF if you remove the {mathptmx} package. Do you know any other way to creat Times New Roman fonts other than using {mathptmx} ?

Comment: What's the error in the `pdflatex` compilation?

Comment: The error massage :  Font \csname\endcsname=psyr at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.

Comment: That message says that your TeX installation is broken.

Comment: !pdfTeX error: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe (file usyr.p
fb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: @egreg: Well "broken" is a hard word. I would say that a font is not installed or the map file has not been updated (depending which of the two error messages is still effective). And the source is either the standard "texniccenter is blocking installation"-problem or the standard "in a multi user setup local maps must be updated manually by calling updmap". Royce: Compile once on the command line and then show me the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer With a base package such as `mathptmx` this should not happen. The URW font package seems missing.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. The error message is as following :  `{C:/Users/ss/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
! Font \csname\endcsname=psyr at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.  
<to be read again>   
                   \endgroup \set@typeset@protect   
l.13 \end{document}  
                   
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,`  The BIGGER problem I found that : I can not compile LaTex=> PDF at all, whereas LaTex=> PS is perfectly working. [The earlier pdf output is through laTeX=> PS => PDF].  Thanks

Comment: Install with the package manager the package `symbol`. After the installation execute on the command line `updmap`. Then try again to compile with pdflatex.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. Now LaTex => PDF working fine and the symbol \hbar coming perfectly.  There is a small problem though. Since I have many eps figures, I need to run LaTeX => PS => PDF compilation and during this again my \hbar symbol is wrong. Could you help .

Comment: Run at first the update manager in admin and user mode. If the problem persist: Run on the command line `findtexmf psfonts.map`. It will show you the path of a map file. Put the map-file somewhere for download for inspection.

Comment: I did all the steps suggested by you, but still not working. I completely deleted the map files (the whole folder) and updated the MikTex. I found that, 'psfonts_t1.map' is the file responsible for PS=> PDF conversion. I completely updated that too. Only one character [\hbar] is creating all the problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, At last I found a remedy. Using `txfonts` package actually solves the problem. Also I have to disable `amssymb` which is not essential. So now everything is OKay. Thanks Ficher for all your help, that indeed make me wiser on this teX world :)

Comment: You didn't find a remedy: the font is still not working. You sidestepped the problem. Btw: I didn't tell you to delete things but to show the map-file. If a font works with pdflatex but not with latex + dvips this normally means that the font name in the map file is wrong (dvips is more picky).

Comment: here is link for psfonts.map file  [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?e0s3n14cp8geeye).  Also for psfonts_t1.map file [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?tlgupe9hcou4723). I guess both are same. All others dvips files can be found here [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?cldc9d4kllht5).  Let me know if you need any other files. Thanks @UlrikeFischer

Comment: You are not embedding the fonts. Open your local updmap.cfg with `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap`. Add `dvipsDownloadBase35 true`. Save the file. Call `updmap`. Then try again.